# Difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, generics, ilist, icollection

What is the difference between `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`?

I've seen many framework classes implementing both these interfaces, therefore I would like to know what advantages one get by implementing both?

Please have a look how they've been defined:

```
public interface IEnumerable
{
    [DispId(-4)]
    IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

As we see, `IEnumerable<T>` derives from `IEnumerable`, that means whatever `IEnumerable` has, `IEnumerable<T>` inherits, then why do we implement both instead of just `IEnumerable<T>`? Is implementing `IEnumerable<T>` not enough?

Likewise, there are other similar pairs:

- `IList` and `IList<T>`
- `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>`

I would like to know about these as well.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Basically the nongeneric interfaces came first, in .NET 1.0 and 1.1. Then when .NET 2.0 came out, the generic equivalents came out. Life would have been a lot simpler if generics had made it into .NET 1.0 :)

In terms of implementing "only" `IEnumerable<T>` instead of both - you basically *have* to implement both, and you have to use explicit interface implementation too, given that both define a parameterless `GetEnumerator` method. As `IEnumerator<T>` extends `IEnumerator` too, it's normally something like this:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    // Return real iterator
}

// Explicit implementation of nongeneric interface
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    // Delegate to the generic implementation
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

On the other hand, with the iterator blocks introduced in C# 2 (with `yield return` etc) you rarely need to implement these things entirely by hand, fortunately. You may need to write something like the above, and then use `yield return` in the `GetEnumerator` method.

Note that `IList<T>` does *not* extend `IList`, and `ICollection<T>` does *not* extend `ICollection`. That's because it's less type-safe to do so... whereas any generic iterator can be seen as a nongeneric iterator due to the (potentially boxing) conversion of any value to `object`, `IList` and `ICollection` allow values to be *added* to the collection; and it doesn't make sense to add (say) a string to an `IList<int>`.

EDIT: The reason why we need `IEnumerable<T>` is so that we can iterate in a type-safe way, and propagate that information around. If I return an `IEnumerable<string>` to you, you know that you can safely assume everything returned from it will be a string reference or null. With `IEnumerable`, we had to effectively cast (often implicitly in a `foreach` statement) each element that was returned from the sequence, because the `Current` property of `IEnumerator` is just of type `object`. As for why we *still* need `IEnumerable` - because old interfaces never go away, basically. There's too much existing code using it.

It would have been possible for `IEnumerable<T>` not to extend `IEnumerable`, but then any code wanting to make use of an `IEnumerable<T>` couldn't call into a method accepting `IEnumerable` - and there were a lot of methods like that from .NET 1.1 and 1.0.

Comment: @Jon: the question is: why do we even need to implement `IEnumerable` when we already implement `IEnumerable<T>`, or vice-versa?

Comment: @Nawaz: I've edited my answer. How comfortable are you with the idea of why generics are a good thing?

Comment: @Jon: The edit is good. thanks. Now what I understand is that `IEnumerable` is there for backward compatibility, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: Mostly. Basically there's a lot of code using it - you can't really remove a public interface after you've released it.

Comment: Jon you really are a truly amazing c# guru, keep up the good work! This helped alot!

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It's unclear why you're asking this as a comment on this answer. If you have a separate question, please *ask* it as a separate question.

Answer (score 11):

One returns an object of type Object, the other returns an object of type T.

Answer (score 3):

As to why you see classes defining both, enough though IEnumerable< T > implements IEnumerable, its not needed but is is nice in a self documenting to list the sub interfaces at times. Consider

```
interface IA { }
interface IB : IA { }

class A : IB {} // legal, IB implements IA

class B : IA, IB {} // also legal, possible more clear on intent
```

Answer (score -1):

While iterating through the loop IEnumerator maintains the state.
It remembers the cursor position and IEnumerable does not.

Comment: That was not the question.