# IQueryable vs IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I'm simply wondering why there is a `IQueryable<T>` version without the generic capability ?

Comment: Definition: "Provides functionality to evaluate queries against a specific data source wherein the type of the data is not specified.". For instance, you can return array of anonymous type from web api controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The generic `IQueryable<T>` is the one you use most often in method
>   signatures and the like. The **non-generic `IQueryable` exist primarily to
>   give you a weakly typed entry point primarily for dynamic query
>   building scenarios**.

by Matt Warren from [LINQ: Building an IQueryable Provider - Part I](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx)

You should use generic `IQueryable<T>` everywhere it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it's the same reason as Jon Skeet gives in  [Difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972170/difference-between-ienumerable-and-ienumerablet) , to allow use in a `foreach` loop. `IQuerable` would be castable to `IEnumerable`, whereas `IQueryable<T>` would not.

Also see Marcin's answer about use in dynamic query building scenarios.

Comment: Type does not have to implement `IEnumerable` to be usable by `foreach` loop.

Comment: While technically true, I think it would be the easiest path to implementing those iterator hooks used under the covers. You could make the same argument for any of the other iterator types mentioned in the SO question I quoted.