# Why can use Regex class like a Data source when declare

Tags: regex, linq

[image]

As you can see in the above picture I  can use Regex class like a data source when declaring it. Why is that?

And I also noticed this LinQ lines are starting with dots. How is this possible?

Comment: You want to ask why we can use static methods of the `Regex` class and why a dot is used to access `Regex` class methods/properties?

Comment: Yeah man,
on MDSN : var wordQuery = from word in words. But my case is 'Regex' class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Regex.Matches(string, string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`MatchCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) instance which implements  `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`. So you can't use LINQ directly since the LINQ extension methods in [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx) require `IEnumerable<T>`(the generic version, [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972170/difference-between-ienumerable-and-ienumerablet)).

That's why `Enumerable.OfType` was used. This returns `IEnumerable<Match>`, so now you can use LINQ. Instead of `OfType<Match>` he could also have used `Cast<Match>`.

In general you can use `Linq-To-Objects` with any kind of type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, even with a [`String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) since it implements `IEnumerable<char>`. A small example which creates a dictionary of chars and their occurrences:

```
Dictionary<char, int> charCounts = "Sample Text" // bad example because only unique letters but i hope you got it
  .GroupBy(c => c)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

To answer the .dot part of your question. LINQ basically consists of many extension methods, so you call them also like any other method, you could use one line:

```
Dictionary<char, int> charCounts = "Sample Text".GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```